# How to access a variable in another window?

Tags: c++builder

I'm trying to access a variable in `Form2` by calling a function `Funkcja()` in `Form1`, but I'm getting an "access violation" error. In this case it looks like this:

> Ustring.cpp: Project Project1.exe raised exception class 0xc0000005 with message 'Exception 0xc0000005 encountered at address 0x175ee0: Access violation reading location 0x000006d8'.

Whether `String A` is in `private` or `public` in `Form2`.

```
UnicodeString& UnicodeString::operator=(const UnicodeString& src)
{
    System::Internal::Strhlpr::UnicodeAssign(*this, const_cast<UnicodeString&>(src));
    return *this;
}
```

Unit1.cpp

```
#include "Unit2.h"

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  Form2->Funkcja();
}
```

Unit2.h

```
class TForm2 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    void __fastcall FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action);
private:    // User declarations

public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm2(TComponent* Owner);

       String A;
       void __fastcall Funkcja();
};
```

Unit2.cpp

```
void __fastcall TForm2::Funkcja()
{
   Form2->A = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Access Violation error means you are accessing the `A` data member via an invalid `TForm2` object pointer.

Inside of `TForm2::Funkcja()`, you should be using the `this` pointer instead of the global `Form2` pointer, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm2::Funkcja()
{
   this->A = "";
   // or simply:
   // A = "";
}
```

If the code still crashes after making that change, then it means the `Form2` pointer being used by `TForm1::Button1Click()` is not pointing at a valid `TForm2` object.

For instance, if the `Form2` object hasn't been created yet when `Funkcja()` is called on it. Or, if it has been created, but the `Form2` pointer was not updated to point at it.  There is simply not enough context provided to diagnose the root cause of the error.